# GeoServer layer preview doesn't work for chinese columns or columns that has underscore in name

Tags: geoserver, sld, encoding

I am learning to use GeoServer. I published a layer from a shp, which I created by importing a csv file into QGIS in utf-8 encoding, and exporting as shp in utf-8 encoding. I added a style to the layer. I got the style from geoserver cookbook for [point with default label](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/c434c7ac14578ccd05a4c25d281d0226/point_pointwithdefaultlabel.sld). The only thing I changed is the contents in `<ogc:PropertyName>`, as I have to set it to the name of the column I want to show. I changed it into `school_name`. But then the layer doesn't show in layer preview.

Things I've tried:

1. change `<ogc:PropertyName>` content to the column `lat`. This column contains latitude. The type shown on GeoServer is double. This works.
2. change `<ogc:PropertyName>` content to `school`. This column contains Chinese characters. The type shown on GeoServer is string. The layer shows but the labels are ??.
3. change `<ogc:PropertyName>` content to `school` and change the xml encoding to utf-8 and UTF-8. Again, the layer shows, but the labels are ??
4. change `<ogc:PropertyName>` content to `school` and add `format_options=CHARSET:UTF-8` in the WMS request. Again, the layer shows, but the labels are ??.
5. change content to `postal_code`. This column contains postcodes which are just numbers. The type shown on GeoServer is long. The layer doesn't show.

So how do I show Chinese labels? And how do I fix the problem where column names with underscore doesn't show?

Comment: make sure you correctly set the character encoding when you imported the shapefile

Comment: I set the encoding of the data store (type Directory of spatial files) to UTF-8. Now it shows boxes instead of question marks, but still not the correct characters. Also, I've ensured to set the encoding of the shp to UTF-8 when exporting the file, re-added the data store to geoserver, and republished the layer. But still not working, as in 1. still not showing the correct chinese characters 2. if label is set to columns with underscore in its name, the entire layer doesn't show

Comment: Are you using a font with Chinese characters in it?

Comment: No, I am using all the same properties as in the cookbook, so my font is Arial.

Comment: By the way I've solve one of the problem. I found what is wrong with the underscore problem. I think it's because the column names in my data that have underscore exceeds 10 characters and Geoserver only excepts 10. So if I change `postal_code` to `postal_cod`, it works, and if I change `school_name` to `school_nam`, the layer shows, although the characters are still square because the data are Chinese characters.

Comment: Can you reopen the question? I think the mistake I made are different (as in more) from the other post you referenced.

Comment: To correct one of my comments above, in Word the font actually remains a Chinese font even when you manually set it to an English font. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how my problem was eventually fixed. I made two key mistakes regarding the Chinese character problem (dbf encoding encoding setting in data store and font in sld), and one mistake regarding the underscore problem (column name length).

**Chinese Character Problem**

This is actually an encoding and font problem. The first mistake I made was not setting the dbf encoding when creating the data store of shp directories. To fix these mistakes, set the dbf encoding as in the image. In this case the correct encoding is utf8 (see figure).
[image: Figure 1: setting the correct dbf encoding for the data store]

The second mistake I made is using font `Arial` (the font from the cookbook), this caused the characters to appear as boxes. To fix this mistake, change the font to `DFKai-SB`, which is a font for Chinese characters. I didn't test with other fonts for Chinese characters, but I assume they will work as well.

**(EDITED) Underscore Problem**

This is actually a problem with the length of the column name of shp files. `school_name` and `postal_code` both have 11 characters. It seems shp will truncate after 10 characters. Opening the attribute table of the shp in QGIS, I found that the column names were `school_nam` and `postal_nam`. So the problem was fixed by changing `<ogc:PropertyName>` content to `school_nam`. Also, checking the Feature Type Details on GeoServer tells me the column names I should use (see figure).

note: The layer created from the csv in QGIS had the correct column names. But after exporting it as a shp and re-importing it to QGIS, I could see that the names were truncated. So take caution that the column names of the shp may be different from the original layer used to create it.
[image]

Comment: Actually, it is shapefiles that truncate your field names to 10 chars - apparently it is a feature!

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I've just checked. The layer created from the csv had the correct attribute names. BUT after exporting to shp they were truncated. I unconsciously assumed the two layers would be the same, which lead me to think it was GeoServer that truncated the name. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#creation-issues ~ `Attribute names can only be up to 10 characters long. Starting with version 1.7, the OGR Shapefile driver tries to generate unique field names. Successive duplicate field names, including those created by truncation to 10 characters, will be truncated to 8 characters and appended with a serial number from 1 to 99`